# How track data with Angular and Google Analytic?

Tags: html, angular, google-analytics

I work on a one single page application (360 virtual visit) with Angular 11. I would like to track user events and especially on buttons.

I started to put the Global site tag in my Index.html file like this: [Global Site tag in Index.html](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AU1je.png)

On google analytic, I receive connection data user [First Data User](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hGQpy.png)

But I have no idea how I can track bouton click with Angular.

Does anyone have an idea that works today ?

do not hesitate to ask me questions for more information. :D
Thank you in advance for your answers. I would share my progress.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

We've added the same feature recently and this guide [here](https://medium.com/madhash/how-to-properly-add-google-analytics-tracking-to-your-angular-web-app-bc7750713c9e), albeit a bit dated, explains it quite well.

It boils down to you using a dedicated `GoogleAnalyticsService` that enables you track specific events (ie. button clicks, scroll events, etc).

Answer (score 0):

For something like **Button Clicks**, you have to configure custom events in Google Analytics and push that custom event whenever user clicks the button.

You can create `onButtonClick()` function and call it when user clicks the button. In the function, you should push event to the `window.dataLayer`:

```js
onButtonClick() {
  window.dataLayer.push({
    event: 'button_click',
    data: {
      user: this.current_user._id,
      ... // Send some custom data that you want to track
    }
  })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be careful with SPA when you install gtag the way it is described into docs as it will track page views incorrect. In SPA browser loads the page only once, and all other actions will rerender the content but it still will not be counted as a views.

Instead you will need to set up router events. Here is a great [tutorial](https://www.dottedsquirrel.com/google-analytics-angular/) for that. It also will explain how to set up other events like button clicks.

By the way in the example above they suggest to send user id with event. Instead of it you may send it with config only once, and it will be automatically added to any your event:

```
gtag('config', 'GA-ID', {
                    page_path: event.urlAfterRedirects,
                    user_id: this.user.id
                });
```

Comment: Normally you don't need to change anything in your code. You can just install Google Analytics and Google Tag Manager on your website (these are the only code changes). Then you just need to configure the Google Tag Manager to send events to your Google Analytics property. This is the most accurate [tutorial](https://nwebstage.napkyn.com/2018/05/02/deploying-google-analytics-for-angular-5) I've found atm

Comment: Well, what worked with universal analytics is not always good for GA4. The way described in that tutorial I suggested is the only way which worked for my app. But thank you for your comment!

Answer (score 0):

You need to configure the Google tag manager to send events to Google Analytics. I've written a post about it: https://pieterjandeclippel.medium.com/angular-or-react-or-whatever-and-google-analytics-97342c909e61

Now it seems that Universal analytics will be on its way out, so you might want to try GA4 instead.

[image: Google Universal Analytics vs GA4]

But I haven't tried with that one yet, since my own website has been configured to use UA.